# Vim: Make f (t,F,T) continue on line breaks

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, normal-mode

I just found out about `f` and its siblings (`t`,`F`,`T`) and naturally I am intrigued (they seem slightly more efficient than using `/` - especially with commands like `d`). But they do not follow line breaks. For instance:

```
my text
more text
```

Let's pretend I was on the `y` in the first line in normal mode. If I type `fr` I would expect to go to the `r` in the second line. But it stops at the end of line.

Is there a way to tell these commands to wrap around?

Answer (score 0):

*[Edit: Changing* No *to* Probably *but keeping original answer for reference. See below.]*

No. See

```
:help left-right-motions
```

---

**Edit:**

Probably. There is an example of mapping `f` to a function that performs a case-insenstive find at the end of

```
:help getchar()
```

That could be easily modified to perform a search for the given character instead of just a find.

To get this to work as a motion command following `d`, for example, you would have to define `f` as an operator-pending mapping. See

```
:help omap-info
```

I wrote "probably" rather than "yes" because I don't have any personal experience with operator-pending mappings so I haven't verified that that will work in this case.

Comment: When I said *Is there a way" I actually meant "How", because I'm sure that it works somehow. Via some mapping to a function or something, perhaps? I don't know enough of the Vim scripting language to figure it out, but I think it should be possible.

Comment: I looked but didn't find anything promising. Apparently I didn't look hard enough. Take a look at `:help getchar()` and scroll to the bottom. There's an example that 'redefines "f" to ignore case.' With a little work, you could make it search additional lines. To get this to work as a motion command following `d`, for example, you'll have to define `f` as an operator-pending mapping. See `:help omap-info`. Sorry I don't have a ready-made solution at the moment.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: Thank you. How's that?